# Passing request object to service in Nest, is it okay?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, nestjs, nest

I'm trying to handle authorization process in my nest app, and in different controllers across app I have to write userId to session.
Usual way is to do something like this:

```js
  @Get('callback')
  handleCallback(
    @Req() req,
  ) {
    const userId = this.authService.loginUser();
    req.session.userId = userId;
  }
```

But I have to duplicate this code in many controllers, so I wanna move it to some separate part of code, maybe something like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class SessionService {
  write(req, userId: number) {
    req.session.userId = userId;
  }

  read(req) {
    return req.session.userId;
  }
}
```

Is it good approach to pass request object directily to service? Or it shouldn't be a service, but maybe helper, etc? Or I just have to duplicate this logic in all controllers?

Comment: Isn't that a scenario for a [middleware](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware)?

Comment: Do you mean to use middleware instead controller? 
If understood you correctly, middleware is not an option for this situation because it executed before controller, but I need to handle some logic inside controller.

Comment: I don't really see what logic, but fine

Comment: I'd use guards for that. If the login didn't succeed, you could return `false`

Comment: Maybe my question is a bit uncear, but the main thing here is about where can put "req.session.userId = userId" part. Will it be okay use separate "SessionService" for this, or no?

Answer (score 1):

This honestly feels like opinionated than anything a solid answer can be given to. Sure you *can* pass the request object to the service, but you *can* also just pass the parts needed. Whatever feels cleanest is *usually* the best approach. But again, super opinionated answer.